# PHP checklist get ID and value and store it

Tags: php, mysql, forms

So I have a form to add a new item to database with a  checkbox as follows

[image]

[image]

So my difficulty is the checkbox. I can easily enough create the array for all items checked but I need an ID for them along with it. I've tried to think of many ways and searched a lot but I just can't think of a way to get the ID in a way that is then useable to me along with the name of the feature (checklist). Since I have to get each feature item and add it to the table houses_has_features.

```
<?php
$title = 'Add a new house';
require_once 'header.php';
require_once 'nav.php';
require_once 'mysqli-con.php';

$conn = new MYSQLI($hn, $un, $pw, $db);

// If house name and type is set then add them into the database
if( !empty($_POST['h_name']) && !empty($_POST['h_type']) ) {
    $house_name = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['h_name']);
    $house_type = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['h_type']);

    //show names added
    echo '<b>House name: </b>'.$house_name . '<br><b> House type:</b>  ' . $house_type;

    $query = "INSERT INTO `house_names` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, '$house_name')";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (!$result) die ("<b class='text-danger'><p>Insert failed ERRROR: " . $conn->error. "</p>");

    global $house_name_id;
    $house_name_id = $conn->insert_id;
    $query = "INSERT INTO `house_types` VALUES ('$house_name_id', '$house_type')";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (!$result) die ("<b class='text-danger'><p>Insert failed ERRROR: " . $conn->error. "</p>");
    } else {
    global $house_name_id;
    $house_name_id= NULL;
    }



//Start container for page content
echo '<div class="container">';

//Display an error message if house name is filled in but not house type
if ( !empty($_POST['h_name']) && empty($_POST['h_type']) || empty($_POST['h_name']) && !empty($_POST['h_type']) ) {
    echo "<p class='error-text'>* Please fill in both the house name and house type *</p>";
}




$query_feat = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM features');
$rows = $query_feat->num_rows;


$features_list  = $_POST['check_list'];
$feature_id = $_POST['feature_id'];
//display checked boxes.
if(isset($_POST['check_list'])) {
    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($features_list); $i++){

        //echo '<br>House name id:' . $house_name_id . '<br> $_POST[] = ' . "$features_list[]";
        print_r($features_list); echo '<br>';
        print_r($feature_id);
    }
}




// Add house form
echo <<<_END


    <h1>Add a house</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <form action="add.php" method="post">
        <p>House Name: <input type="text" name="h_name"></p>
        <p>House type: <input type="text" name="h_type"></p>
        <b>features:</b> 
        <ul class="list-group">
_END;
        for ($c = 0 ; $c < $rows ; ++$c){

        $query_feat->data_seek($c);
        $feat = $query_feat->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);


        echo '<li><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="' .$feat[1]. '">'.$feat[1].'</li>';

}


echo <<<_END
        <ul>
        <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>

_END;



require_once 'footer.php';
```

I'm really lost on this one any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your value of checkbox to id or anything you want.

```
<li><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="' .$feat[0]. '">'.$feat[1].'</li>
```

$feat[1] => $feat[0] or else

Comment: Aaaaahhh wow I can't believe I missed this. I only need to output the name and store the ID so why am I trying to store both lol. Your explanation is not easy to understand but I think I get what you mean.

Comment: have you change your value of checkbox to array that contain ID??

Comment: Yeah I changed it to '<li><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="' .$feat[0]. '">'.$feat[1].'</li>';

Comment: lol. sorry if my explanation confusing you. is the problem solve now??

Comment: I think so man. Still have to figure out how I am going to enter all this into the database. I feel kinda stupid now lol. Thanks for the help :) saved me from being stumped all day.

Comment: got it all sorted out now man and it's working great! I can add to the database perfectly thanks for the help lol. I'm not sure the question is really correct though should I delete it?